# how to install Expect for windows using ActiveTCL 8.6 x86

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to install Expect for Windows using ActiveTCL and I'm having a helluva time. I understand I need to use teacup/teapot? Is there any documentation at all? I'm trying to run teacup and it says "can't create directory" on my network drive, it's trying to install in a random directory that I can't seem to change..

I've spent a day trying to figure out how to install, what I thought would be, a simple program...

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm encountering this problem under VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

I am convinced that Expect does not work on 8.6, at least as advertised by the documentation on ActiveTcl's site.  I have spent the last three hours trying to get it to work without success.  I uninstalled Tcl 8.6, and downgraded to 8.5 (32 bit).  Once that was done, I opened the "Tclsh" application and ran the command "teapot install Expect"  That is probably not the solution you are looking for, but that's what I did.

Comment: your answer is still relevant! after almost 3 years ahahahha, congrats :P

Answer (score 0):

Run command "teacup install Except" in prompt.
You can type "teacup help" to find more information.

Comment: I installed the latest ActiveTCL, there is no teacup in the bin folder. What I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Thanks for this post @Sean Farley!  Adding Expect to ActiveTcl was a clear as mud.  I agree that it does not seem to be supported in Tcl 8.6 or 64-bit Tcl 8.5.  After installing & uninstalling both of those the 32-bit version worked (also I think it's "**teacup install Expect**" to install).